# Auto iteration iterates past the vectors end (I think)

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to code a PacMan game with c++ and OpenGL. At the moment I am having some trouble when trying to delete a "Coin" pointer from a vector of "GameObject" pointers:

```
bool MovableObject::collisionHandling(std::vector<GameObject*>& v) {
    bool deleteCoin = false;
    int vectorIt;

    for (auto it = begin(v); it != end(v); ++it) {
        if (*it != this) {
            // If there is a collision imminent:
            if (collisionInt(this, *it)) {
                // For PacMan:
                if (this->classType == "PacMan") {
                    // Collision with coin:
                    if ((*it)->classType == "Coin") {
                        PacMan* ptr = static_cast<PacMan*>(this);
                        ptr->score += 10;
                        vectorIt = it - v.begin();
                        deleteCoin = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (deleteCoin) {
        Coin* ptr = static_cast<Coin*>(v[vectorIt]);
        v.erase(v.begin() + vectorIt);
        delete ptr;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This throws an exception in a vector file, which reads:
*Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Mycont was nullptr*. The exception is thrown on line 72, which has the following code:

`_STL_VERIFY(_Ptr < _Mycont->_Mylast, "can't increment vector iterator past end")`

It seems like the exception gets thrown between another for loop, where the collisionHandling function gets called from:

```
void GameLevel::update(GLFWwindow *window) {
    std::string classType;

    // Delta time:
    float timeSinceStart = float(glfwGetTime());
    deltaTime = timeSinceStart - oldTimeSinceStart;
    oldTimeSinceStart = timeSinceStart;

    if (!paused) {
        std::cout << "Testing...";

        // We don't need to update walls:
        for (auto it = begin(objectsPtr); it != end(objectsPtr); ++it) {
            classType = (*it)->classType;

            if (classType == "Ghost") {
                Ghost* ptr = static_cast<Ghost*>(*it);
                ptr->deltaTime = deltaTime;

                ptr->pickRandomOffDirection();
                ptr->updateSpeed();
                ptr->collisionHandling(objectsPtr);
                ptr->move();
                ptr->animate();
            }
            else if (classType == "PacMan") {
                PacMan* ptr = static_cast<PacMan*>(*it);
                ptr->deltaTime = deltaTime;

                ptr->input(window);
                ptr->updateSpeed();
                paused = ptr->collisionHandling(objectsPtr);
                ptr->move();
                ptr->animate();
            }
        }
        std::cout << "complete\n";
    }
```

As I understand it, this shouldn't throw an exception. (Testing similar code with a vector of ints, where the last element was erased in the loop didn't fail.) This code also worked properly until I added the collision with coin part, so I know it has something to do with the vector loop. Additionally, this only fails when some specific coins should get deleted. Most of them get deleted without any problem.

I appreciate any feedback or attempt to help me.

Just in case you need more information, the collisionHandling function contains more code, but I don't think it has anything to do with the error. Here is the full code:

```
bool MovableObject::collisionHandling(std::vector<GameObject*>& v) {
    bool deleteCoin = false;
    int vectorIt;

    for (auto it = begin(v); it != end(v); ++it) {
        if (*it != this) {
            // If there is a collision imminent:
            if (collisionInt(this, *it)) {
                // For PacMan:
                if (this->classType == "PacMan") {
                    // Collision with wall:
                    if ((*it)->classType == "GameObject") {
                        bool xCollision = false, yCollision = false;
                        glm::vec2 oldSpeed = speed;

                        // Check x-axis:
                        speed.y = 0.f;
                        xCollision = collisionInt(this, *it);

                        // Check y-axis:
                        speed.y = oldSpeed.y;
                        speed.x = 0.f;
                        yCollision = collisionInt(this, *it);

                        speed = glm::vec2(!xCollision * oldSpeed.x, !yCollision * oldSpeed.y);
                    }
                    // Collision with ghost
                    if ((*it)->classType == "Ghost") {
                        std::cout << "GAME OVER\n";
                        return true;
                    }
                    // Collision with coin:
                    if ((*it)->classType == "Coin") {
                        PacMan* ptr = static_cast<PacMan*>(this);
                        ptr->score += 10;
                        vectorIt = it - v.begin();
                        deleteCoin = true;
                    }
                }
                // For Ghost:
                else if (this->classType == "Ghost") {
                    // Collision with wall:
                    if ((*it)->classType == "GameObject") {
                        // Same as with PacMan:
                        bool xCollision = false, yCollision = false;
                        glm::vec2 oldSpeed = speed;

                        // Check x-axis:
                        speed.y = 0.f;
                        xCollision = collisionInt(this, *it);

                        // Check y-axis:
                        speed.y = oldSpeed.y;
                        speed.x = 0.f;
                        yCollision = collisionInt(this, *it);

                        speed = glm::vec2(!xCollision * oldSpeed.x, !yCollision * oldSpeed.y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (deleteCoin) {
        Coin* ptr = static_cast<Coin*>(v[vectorIt]);
        v.erase(v.begin() + vectorIt);
        delete ptr;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour, `it` is invalidated in for loop inside `update` by `collisionHandling`. `collisionHandling` iterates over the same container, calling `erase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [rafix07](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8950365/rafix07) for pointing out my mistake in a comment:

> Undefined behaviour, it is invalidated in for loop inside update by collisionHandling. collisionHandling iterates over the same container, calling erase

I fixed this by deleting the desired object after the for loop inside the update method, instead of inside the collisionHandling method.